# Why using `attr(x, "class")` instead of `class(x)`?

Tags: r, class, attr

The function `model.frame.default` runs the following code; `is.null(attr(data, "class"))`. My question is, why using `attr` in this case? Wouldn't it be more straight forward to use `is.null(class(data))`? (And doesn't it contradict to what is said here: [Why is names(x) better than attr(x, "names")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046953/why-is-namesx-better-than-attrx-names))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equivalent. Compare the output of `class(1)` with `attr(1, "class")`. The latter returns only explicit S3 classes, the former also implicit classes.

Comment: So, it is a developper's choice whether he wants to rely only on explicit S3 classes (then he uses attr(x, "class"))?

Comment: Sometimes you only need to know about explicit classes, sometimes also about implicit classes. It depends on your application. Note that there is also `is.object`.